# How to save date_time when check-box is checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

In my Person model i have a datetime attribute named

> hired

I want to setup its value when user checks a check_box.

how to do this? check_box has 2 values: 1 and 0 (or true / false), but i need to have hired=Time.now. Should i do this somehow in Person model? I guess that i should create in my model a method that should be called before_save, i.e.:

```
def set_hiring_date 

  if self.hired==true
    self.hired=Time.now
  end

end
```

Is my approach ok?

Answer (score 0):

well - it is my solution.

1. new, "fake" attribute hiring_state for Person.

> ```
>   def hiring_state=(arg)
>     @hiring_state=arg
>   end
> ```

2. new method in Person, executed before_save:

> ```
>   def set_hiring_date
>     if @hiring_state=="1" && !hired?
>       self.hired=Time.now
>     elsif @hiring_state=="0" && hired?
>       self.hired=nil
>     end
>   end
> ```

3. in my form:

> ```
>   `<%= f.check_box :hiring_state, checked: @person.hired? %>`
> ```

4. and of course additional attribute :hiring_state accepted in params in my controller